# Drupal Theme Installation Error

Tags: themes, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I am new at Drupal and Whene I try to install a new theme it directs me to authorize.php page showing an Error Message saying that I'm not using an encrypted connection, so my password will be sent in plain text as the image shows:

[image]

Comment: Please post the images as images and not as links. Not many people will actually open the links to look at the images, so if you want people to look at the images and therefore have a better chance to help you, it's better if you post them directly as images.